# Calculate the coordinates of a set of vectors with regards to a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I was studying for a midterm of Linear Algebra and I'm stuck with part b of this problem. I'd like to point out this is my first time using LaTeX so I'm sorry if it is a little bit messy. I've looked already for similar questions on this page but found only answers related to part A. Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

Let $B=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ be a basis of a vector space V.

**1. Prove the set $C= \{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is also a basis of V where:**
$$v_1=u_1+u_2+u_3,v_2=u_1-u_2+u_3,v_3=u_2-u_3$$

**My work:**

I've written each vector of C with regards to the basis B and constructed a matrix with them.The resulting matrix would be the following:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0\\
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & -1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
I then calculate the rank of it and since it is 3, it is linearly independent and it spans V which implies it is a basis of V.

**2. Calculate the coordinates with regards to the basis C for each of the vectors $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$**

**My work so far:**

As far as I know, coordinates of a vector $v$ with regards to a given basis are the coefficients of the linear combination of the basis to express that vector. That is what I did in part A where:
$$[v_1]_B= \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$[v_2]_B= \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$[v_3]_B= \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$
So I assumed if they were asking for the vectors of B with regards to the basis C, I would have to solve this system of equations and the solutions would be the coordinates. But I'm not sure if it is right nor how to solve it.
$$u_1=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\alpha_3v_3$$
$$u_2=\beta_1v_1+\beta_2v_2+\beta_3v_3$$
$$u_3=\omega_1v_1+\omega_2v_2+\omega_3v_3$$
According to this:
$$[u_1]_C= \begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\\alpha_3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$[u_2]_C= \begin{bmatrix}\beta_1\\\beta_2\\\beta_3\end{bmatrix}$$
$$[u_3]_C= \begin{bmatrix}\omega_1\\\omega_2\\\omega_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 
\end{bmatrix}  $ $\;\;$, $\;B_1= \begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3 
\end{bmatrix}  \;\;$, $B_2=\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3 
\end{bmatrix}$

$AB_1=B_2\Rightarrow A^{-1}AB_1=A^{-1}B_2 \Rightarrow B_1=A^{-1}B_2$. Hence,

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 \\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & -1 
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
v_1 \\
v_2 \\
v_3 
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I have used the transpose of the matrix you arrived at. I think you can figure out the coordinates from here.

Comment: Thank you so much!